# Pagination xpath invalid

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, robotframework

I wanted to navigate to next page but the robot always returned error

How do I construct the xpath with this `<li title="2" class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2" tabindex="0">`
or  `<li title="Next Page" class="ant-pagination-next"`

script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser
Library    OperatingSystem
Resource   ../Resources/BrowserParameters.robot
Resource   ../Resources/BrowserResources.robot
Resource   ../Resources/BrowserCustomKeywords.robot

#Select Browser: chromium or firefox
Test Setup      Test Setup    Browser=chromium
Test Teardown   Test Teardown

*** Test Cases ***
001-01-Upload13Videos-Delete2Videos-Upload2Videos-Process
    Click     ${Page-Inference}
    Upload Multiple Video Files
    Click    //title[@class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2"])
```

the outer HTML

```
<ul class="ant-pagination mini ant-table-pagination ant-table-pagination-right" unselectable="unselectable">
    <li title="Previous Page" class="ant-pagination-prev ant-pagination-disabled" aria-disabled="true">
        <button class="ant-pagination-item-link" type="button" tabindex="-1" disabled="">
            <span role="img" aria-label="left" class="anticon anticon-left">
                <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="left" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path d="M724 218.3V141c0-6.7-7.7-10.4-12.9-6.3L260.3 486.8a31.86 31.86 0 000 50.3l450.8 352.1c5.3 4.1 12.9.4 12.9-6.3v-77.3c0-4.9-2.3-9.6-6.1-12.6l-360-281 360-281.1c3.8-3 6.1-7.7 6.1-12.6z"/>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li title="1" class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-1 ant-pagination-item-active" tabindex="0">
        <a rel="nofollow">1</a>
    </li>
    <li title="2" class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2" tabindex="0">
        <a rel="nofollow">2</a>
    </li>
    <li title="Next Page" class="ant-pagination-next" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
        <button class="ant-pagination-item-link" type="button" tabindex="-1">
            <span role="img" aria-label="right" class="anticon anticon-right">
                <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="right" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path d="M765.7 486.8L314.9 134.7A7.97 7.97 0 00302 141v77.3c0 4.9 2.3 9.6 6.1 12.6l360 281.1-360 281.1c-3.9 3-6.1 7.7-6.1 12.6V883c0 6.7 7.7 10.4 12.9 6.3l450.8-352.1a31.96 31.96 0 000-50.4z"/>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

error:

```
    Error: locator.click: DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/title[@class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2"])' is not a valid XPath expression.
    at Object.queryAll (<anonymous>:3:42890)
    at g._queryEngineAll (<anonymous>:3:49586)
    at g._querySelectorRecursively (<anonymous>:3:48960)
    at g.querySelectorAll (<anonymous>:3:49365)
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:3:2389), <anonymous>:10:33)
    at s (<anonymous>:3:51298)
    at <anonymous>:3:51366
    at Object.run (<anonymous>:3:51732)
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:3:2389), <anonymous>:1:14)
    at t.default.evaluate (<anonymous>:3:2412)
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "//title[@class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2"]) >> nth=0"
  Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/title[@class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2"])' is not a valid XPath expression.
============================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this `xpath`

```
//title[@class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2"])
```

which is wrong, cause xPath expression are written like this

```
//tagName[@attributeName='attributeValue']
```

so your xpath should be

```
//li[@class='ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2']
```

Also, You can have this xpath, since you are mainly looking for pagination, index wouldn't hurt [See below]

```
//li[@title='2']
```